# Is there a way to have more than one data type MVP - cardview & presenter

Tags: java, android, android-cardview, android-mvp, presenter

I need to make a single list row consisting of three items each from a different data types. The data types all have the same properties but I do NOT want to combine them in a single list.

I've tried having the models extend the same data type, but this causes the app to crash - "unable to create converter for the class".

Is it possible to have a presenter and a view with three different data types?